# Uninstall of snaps in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: uninstall, snap

I have dual boot install of Ubuntu 22.04 and windows 10 on a Laptop.
Also a desktop with 21.xx which auto upgraded to 22.04. Now both work fine yet I cannot Uninstall any snaps on either machine. I get a no package available error. HELP

Comment: Snaps don't get removed with `apt` - they're removed with `sudo snap remove [snapname]`.  You can get the list of snaps by running `sudo snap list`.  However, be aware that in 22.04 a number of core components are snapped, so removing things may not be the best solution unless you KNOW what you're doing or have backed up your data first.

Comment: Can you elaborate "I cannot Uninstall any snaps"?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1420253/edit) to copy actual (and complete!) terminal input and output from your terminal into your question above. Show us the problem instead of describing the problem.